# Parse HTML syntax using Lex and Yacc

Tags: yacc, lex

How can i parse the HTML syntax using Lex and Yacc. If the syntax is of the following form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>
Content of the document......
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please show us your attempt

Comment: Why? There are three *types* of HTML parser already available, with numerous implementations of each. Why would you want to reinvent this wheel?

Comment: It's possible that what is wanted is to scrape certain parts of the HTML for information retrieval

Comment: If the HTML is always in this specific form with little or no divergence, you don't need a full-blown parser. You can just use regex to achieve the goal much easier.
If the HTML can diverge from this template is some limited way, a parser may be a right solution but we need to know more details to be able to help.
If you need a parser that can handle every HTML, use a ready-made solution. Writing such parser is a big undertaking.

Answer (score -2):

Here is Lex code for HTML it will recognize the tags on the basis of this expression <[^>]*>

```
 %{
   #include<stdio.h>
   %}

 %%
\<[^>]*\> fprintf(yyout,"%s\n",yytext);
.|\n; 
%%

int yywrap()
{
 return 1;
}

int main()
 {
  yyin=fopen("input.html","r");
  yyout=fopen("output7.txt","w");
  yylex();``
  return 0;
 }
```